# Https XMLHttpRequest POST fails on localhost

Tags: javascript, curl, google-chrome-extension, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to automate a repetitive task at work. Basically we have a feature on our website that is similar to the [Piperlime's](http://piperlime.gap.com/browse/product.do?cid=1027763&vid=1&pid=101694002) `Add To Wishlist` feature.
I can succesfully perform a XMLHttpRequest POST on the production website, however the same call performed against the developer, test, and a locally run environment fail.

The websites use `https` protocol. When I run my local environment and access the site I do receive the security warning about trying to connect securely but the browsers can't confirm that the connection is secure, aka the untrusted connection warning.

Locally there is some java backend with jetty and maven. My foo with java is weak so I'm not sure what component is actually serving up the webpage.

However I do not receive the security certificate warning when I hit the dev or test sites.

I can successfully see the network requests go out in the browser debug window. I can grab the http request as a cURL command and succesfullly add items to my wishlist via the command line.

I'm struggling with how to figure out what I'm missing.

FWIW, I'm executing my javascript code as a google extension. Again, the extension works for the production site, but fails for the test/dev/local environments.

Running:
Google Chrome  40.0.2214.115 (64-bit) on Mac OSX 10.9.5

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't have the test/dev/local addresses in my `manifest.json` in the `permissions` section. Once I included those, then the XHR's were completed successfully.